# estou precisando pegar o valor de um elemento json e só me retorna UNDEFINED

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

Estou precisando pegar o valor de um elemento/chave e nao estou conseguindo, pode me dar uma maozinha?

Este é parte do arquivo json retornado,

```
{

  "id": "or_3JOPnAoigiGKEMyQ",

  "code": "QEMC28CPLJ",

  "amount": 152,

  "currency": "BRL",

  "closed": true,

  "items": [

    {

      "id": "oi_KBbAMzNI1cEVWp9G",

      "type": "product",

      "description": "TRANSVAGINAL",

      "amount": 56,

      "quantity": 1,

      "status": "active",

      "created_at": "2021-09-10T16:53:40Z",

      "updated_at": "2021-09-10T16:53:40Z",

      "code": "9"

    },

    ],
```

A pergunta é: pra eu pegar o valor atribuido ao "id" não seria assim? onde eu estou errando?

```
      $.ajax({
    
          url: BASE_URL + 'aprendizado/lerjson',
    
          dataType: "json",
    
          type: 'POST',
    
          success: function (data) {
    
                console.log(data.id); 
          }   
    
    });
    
}
```

Comment: Use `console.log(data);` pra ver a estrutura real do JSON. Pode ser que esteja vindo com algum nome após o `data`.

Answer (score 0):

Vou colocar abaixo o q precisava fazer, caso alguem passe pelo mesmo problema, a solução no meu caso foi esta:

```
$.ajax({
     url: BASE_URL + 'fatura/lerjsonpagarme',
     dataType: "json",
     type: "POST",
     success: function (data) {
        var dados = jQuery.parseJSON(data);  ==> precisava fazer isto
        console.log(dados.id)
                  
     }    
 });
```